# Partitioned key space for StackExchange Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

When developing a component that use Redis, I've found it a good pattern to prefix all keys used by that component so that it does not interfere other components.

Examples:

- A component managing users might use keys prefixed by `user:` and a component managing a log might use keys prefixed by `log:`.
- In a multi-tenancy system I want each customer to use a separate key space in Redis to ensure that their data do not interfere. The prefix would then be something like `customer:<id>:` for all keys related to a specific customer.

Using Redis is still new stuff for me. My first idea for this partitioning pattern was to use separate database identifiers for each partition. However, that seems to be a bad idea because the number of databases is limited and it seems to be a feature that is about to be deprecated.

An alternative to this would be to let each component get an `IDatabase` instance and a `RedisKey` that it shall use to prefix all keys. (I'm using [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis))

I've been looking for an `IDatabase` wrapper that automatically prefix all keys so that components can use the `IDatabase` interface as-is without having to worry about its keyspace. I didn't find anything though.

So my question is: **What is a recommended way to work with partitioned key spaces on top of StackExchange Redis?**

I'm now thinking about implementing my own `IDatabase` wrapper that would prefix all keys. I think most methods would just forward their calls to the inner `IDatabase` instance. However, some methods would require a bit more work: For example [SORT](http://redis.io/commands/sort) and [RANDOMKEY](http://redis.io/commands/randomkey).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've created an `IDatabase` wrapper now that provides a *key space partitioning*.

The wrapper is created by using an extension method to `IDatabase`

```
    ConnectionMultiplexer multiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
    IDatabase fullDatabase = multiplexer.GetDatabase();
    IDatabase partitioned = fullDatabase.GetKeyspacePartition("my-partition");
```

Almost all of the methods in the partitioned wrapper have the same structure:

```
public bool SetAdd(RedisKey key, RedisValue value, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None)
{
    return this.Inner.SetAdd(this.ToInner(key), value, flags);
}
```

They simply forward the invocation to the inner database and prepend the key space prefix to any `RedisKey` arguments before passing them on.

The `CreateBatch` and `CreateTransaction` methods simply creates wrappers for those interfaces, but with the same base wrapper class (as most methods to wrap are defined by `IDatabaseAsync`).

The `KeyRandomAsync` and `KeyRandom` methods are not supported. Invocations will throw a `NotSupportedException`. This is not a concern for me, and to quote @Marc Gravell:

> I can't think of any sane way of achieving that, but I suspect NotSupportedException("RANDOMKEY is not supported when a key-prefix is specified") is entirely reasonable (this isn't a commonly used command anyway)

I have not yet implemented `ScriptEvaluate` and `ScriptEvaluateAsync` because it is unclear to me how I should handle the `RedisResult` return value. The input parameters to these methods accept `RedisKey` which should be prefixed, but the script itself could **return** keys and in that case I think it would make (most) sense to *unprefix* those keys. For the time being, those methods will throw a `NotImplementedException`...

The sort methods (`Sort`, `SortAsync`, `SortAndStore` and `SortAndStoreAsync`) have special handling for the `by` and `get` parameters. These are prefixed as normal unless they have one of the special values: `nosort` for `by` and `#` for `get`.

Finally, to allow prefixing `ITransaction.AddCondition` I had to use a bit reflection:

```
internal static class ConditionHelper
{
    public static Condition Rewrite(this Condition outer, Func<RedisKey, RedisKey> rewriteFunc)
    {
        ThrowIf.ArgNull(outer, "outer");
        ThrowIf.ArgNull(rewriteFunc, "rewriteFunc");

        Type conditionType = outer.GetType();
        object inner = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(conditionType);

        foreach (FieldInfo field in conditionType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            if (field.FieldType == typeof(RedisKey))
            {
                field.SetValue(inner, rewriteFunc((RedisKey)field.GetValue(outer)));
            }
            else
            {
                field.SetValue(inner, field.GetValue(outer));
            }
        }

        return (Condition)inner;
    }
}
```

This helper is used by the wrapper like this:

```
internal Condition ToInner(Condition outer)
{
    if (outer == null)
    {
        return outer;
    }
    else
    {
        return outer.Rewrite(this.ToInner);
    }
}
```

There are several other `ToInner` methods for different kind of parameters that contain `RedisKey` but they all more or less end up calling:

```
internal RedisKey ToInner(RedisKey outer)
{
    return this.Prefix + outer;
}
```

---

I have now created a pull request for this:

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/pull/92

The extension method is now called `WithKeyPrefix` and the reflection hack for rewriting conditions is no longer needed as the new code have access to the internals of `Condition` classes.

Comment: Yup; I pretty much agree with everything you've said there. This could have use in the main library, if you wanted to submit it as a pull request - and fairly easy to review since it is implemented in a decorator pattern rather than hacking the guts to pieces. In particular, I'm thinking extension methods like a `IDatabase GetDatabase(this ConnectionMultiplexer, int db = 0, object asyncState = null, RedisKey keyPrefix = default(RedisKey)`, or `IDatabase WithKeyPrefix(this IDatabase, RedisKey keyPrefix)`. And I'm sure we can make the `Condition` type a bit more key-map friendly...

Comment: Oh, *personally*, I'd be included to *support* the `Script*` methods, simply with the caveat that no remapping will occur to any keys that are **returned** (but keys going *in* are mapped). Although thinking about it, even that might be possible... *if* the caller casts to `RedisKey` rather than to `string` / `byte[]`.

Comment: Excellent. I'll go ahead and do that. But first I'll have to learn how to create pull requests :-) I've never worked with GIT before...

Comment: it can be fun the first time; it gets easier with repetition! But: **fork the project first**; clone your fork to get a local copy on your disk; make the changes to your local copy, and push the commits back to your fork; then go to `https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/compare` and choose your fork.

Comment: Or alternatively - just email me the files, if you really don't want to have to tame git

Comment: Thanks! It seems like fun - I'll give it a go! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Intriguing suggestion. Note that redis *already* offers a simple isolation mechanism by way of *database numbers*, for example:

```
// note: default database is 0
var logdb = muxer.GetDatabase(1);
var userdb = muxer.GetDatabase(2);
```

StackExchange.Redis will handle all the work to issue commands to the correct databases - i.e. commands issued via `logdb` will be issued against database 1.

Advantages:

- inbuilt
- works with all clients
- provides complete keyspace isolation
- doesn't require additional per-key space for the prefixes
- works with `KEYS`, `SCAN`, `FLUSHDB`, `RANDOMKEY`, `SORT`, etc
- you get high-level per-db keyspace metrics via `INFO`

Disadvantages:

- not supported on redis-cluster
- not supported via intermediaries like twemproxy

Note:

- the number of databases is a configuration option; IIRC it defaults to 16 (numbers 0-15), but can be tweaked in your configuration file via:

  ```
  databases 400 # moar databases!!!
  ```

This is actually how we (Stack Overflow) use redis with multi-tenancy; database 0 is "global", 1 is "stackoverflow", etc. It should also be clear that if required, it is then a fairly simple thing to migrate an entire database to  a different node using `SCAN` and `MIGRATE` (or more likely: `SCAN`, `DUMP`, `PTTL` and `RESTORE` - to avoid blocking).

Since database partitioning is not supported in redis-cluster, there may be a valid scenario here, but it should also be noted that redis nodes are easy to spin up, so another valid option is simply: *use different redis groups for each* (different port numbers, etc) - which would also have the advantage of allowing genuine concurrency between nodes (CPU isolation).

---

However, what you propose is not unreasonable; there is actually "prior" here... again, largely linked to how we (Stack Overflow) use redis: while databases work fine for isolating *keys*, no isolation is currently provided by redis for *channels* (pub/sub). Because of this, StackExchange.Redis actually includes a `ChannelPrefix` option on `ConfigurationOptions`, that allows you to specify a prefix that is automatically added during `PUBLISH` and removed when receiving notifications. So if your `ChannelPrefix` is `foo:`, and you publish and event `bar`, the *actual* event is published to the channel `foo:bar`; likewise: any callback you have only sees `bar`. It *could* be that this is something that is viable for databases too, but to emphasize: at the moment this configuration option is at the *multiplexer* level - not the individual `ISubscriber`. To be comparable to the scenario you present, this would need to be at the `IDatabase` level.

Possible, but a decent amount of work. If possible, I would recommend investigating the option of simply using database numbers...

Comment: I can see that using databases for isolation would be the best way to go (for true isolation). But I'm planning to use the Azure Redis cache service. And I don't think it is possible to change the number of supported databases (which is set to `16` by default). 16 is not enough for my scenario.

Comment: @MårtenWikström understood; to do this *inside* the `IDatabase` is a pretty big change, and is not something that is currently supported. It *could be added*, but: it isn't trivial. I *think* most things are possible, **except** `RANDOMKEY`; I can't think of any sane way of achieving that, but I suspect `NotSupportedException("RANDOMKEY is not supported when a key-prefix is specified")` is entirely reasonable (this isn't a commonly used command *anyway*). It may be more appropriate to log it on the issue list for input/consideration (linking to this post).

Comment: Thanks! I did actually go ahead and wrote a simple wrapper. Please see my self-answer for details. In general the only troubling methods I found where `RandomKey`, `ScriptEvaluate` and `AddCondition`.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I am trying to use ChannelPrefix the way you mention it, but it is not partitioning the data the way I expect it to.  I explain the issue a little more in a separate question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859883/stackexchange-redis-channelprefix-not-scoping-keys