# StackExchange Redis ChannelPrefix Not Scoping Keys

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I have channelPrefix declared in my connection string and I can tell by using ConfigurationOptions.Parse that it is correctly parsing out the channelPrefix from the string.  I assumed that if I opened two instances of Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache where they each had the same connection string, except for different channelPrefix values, that Redis would maintain separate values for the keys of the two, but that is not what I am seeing.  When I set a value to a key using one instance of RedisCache, I can retrieve the value from the other instance using the same key.  Am I totally misunderstanding what channelPrefix does or is it possible that our Redis server is configured in a way that does not obey channelPrefix?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a "channel", and the `RedisChannel` type in particular, relates to the pub/sub API, not the keyspace DB API. For what you want, you are after the `.WithKeyPrefix()` extension method on the `IDatabase` that you obtained with `GetDatabase()`.

Comment: I am accessing Redis in these three different ways, and I do not have a way to intercept the database used in any of these cases.  I have access to ConfigurationOptions in all three cases, though, so I was hoping it would be the key to this problem.  I might be able to manually override the keys with a prefix in two cases, but I do not see how to do this with the SignalR backplane.

StackExchangeRedisDataProtectionBuilderExtensions.PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis
new StackExchangeRedis.RedisCache
StackExchangeRedisDependencyInjectionExtensions.AddStackExchangeRedis

Comment: @Eric in theory it could be done at the configuration level; that just isn't an option that exists *today*